# How can I remove the shadow at the top of the unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, themes

I'm using a theme (based on Ambiance Grey) where the slight shadowing that is present at the very top of the Unity launcher is visually disturbing (see image below), and would like to remove it.

[image: pic]

I was able to remove the shadow from the Unity panel by editing

```
/usr/share/unity/icons/panel-shadow.png
```

but I haven't been able to find a similar image that would control the shadowing of the launcher top.

Comment: link to theme...?

Comment: [Numix Dark Red](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme) is one example (it's what I am using), but I'm not sure the specific theme matters to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using Ubuntu 16.04,

**METHOD-1:**

Replace image `/usr/share/unity/icons/panel-shadow.png` with transparent png image.

Edit: I have gave the wrong path before. Please use the same path and file as given above. The below path is also corrected.

Replace `/usr/share/unity/icons/panel-shadow.png` with an invisible image. In other words, edit that PNG file and make it 100% transparent and remove the black shade in the image.

**METHOD-2:**

Or install [compiz manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) and change the setting in window decoration option (If you cant find the option use the search in the tool). There is option to change the active and inactive shadow and its properties also.

Comment: For method 1, I do not have a folder named `/usr/share/unity/3`, so I can't change the second `panel-shadow.png`, the first part was already done. For method 2, to change window decoration, I have to enable the plugin, which forces to disable the unity plugin. In the unity plugin, however, it did have an active and inactive shadow under it's decoration tab, however, it changed the shadow for windows, not the top of the unity launcher. This hasn't solved the problem yet, but thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: I gave the path of Ubuntu 12.04 wrongly before. Please use the edited path. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Both paths you gave are the same as in the question. That shadow (the one under the panel itself) is gone, the other one (above the unity dash icon, as shown in the picture) is the one I'm trying to remove. I've looked around and haven't found the correct file. I'm not sure it is in this folder.